# How To create maven web project - axis2 (Skeleton) using existing ?WSDL dile

Tags: maven, web, soap, jboss, apache-axis

I have the *war file and It had been build soap web services. Now I have not code base above *war file. So I want to re developed the existing *war file. First I try to generate Skeleton using ?wsdl file and try to developed logic. But I have no Idea about how to generate Skeleton using existing ?wsdl file.

Please give me the advice or example, how to develop sop web project, it semiyearly than existing *war project.

*I have only ?wsdl file now. Not used *war file to build new project.

Answer (score 0):

To generate skeleton you may use WSDL2Code / WSDL2Java command line tool: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html
or Eclipse code generator plugin: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html